# "Assembly Missing" when using a class library within a RESTful WCF web service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, dll, remote-server

I've spent the past three days looking for a solution but nothing seems to fit the bill. Firstly, I'm new to WCF - I'm currently learning IIS, WCF and the REST architecture style for my final year project of my undergraduates degree.

I'm currently working on a simple read-only web service to get me started, my web service is hosted on IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 R2 inside my LAN on a remote server. I'm connecting to my server through FTP inside of Visual Studio 2010; my Visual Studio solution consists of a WCF web service project and a class library. When I reference my classes in Service.svc inline to my service description, everything works fine, but I would prefer my service contract and classes to be kept separate for clarity. When I move my classes into a class library, reference the project in Visual Studio and build the web site, everything appears in place, I can see the .dll being copied to my web server (verified through Remote Connection) and Visual Studio shows no errors. However when I navigate to an endpoint, i get a Compilation Error with code CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XXX'  could not be found.

Am I missing something here?

To reiterate here is what I am doing when referencing a .dll:

1. Adding a reference to the web service solution (I've tried both referencing the Project and Browsing to the .dll file - both to no avail).
2. Adding a using statement to Service.svc where my custom classes are instantiated and used.
3. Saving the solution.
4. Build -> Build Web Site (Success with no errors, I can see the .dll being uploaded to the server at the bottom of the window.)

Any help would be appreciated, if further details are required please ask, I feel like I'm missing something in the process.

Thanks in advance, Andy

Comment: Not helpful to your actual problem, but when you want to write an RESTful web service, then you should really consider using the ASP.NET web API, instead of WCF. It's more suited for RESTful web services accessible via HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just made a quick google search and it looks interesting, it could be included in my final year project. I'll definitely explore it further, I am enjoying WCF quite a bit though, and have spent the past couple of months reading up on it; something else to explore though, cheers! :)